# Lost Internet, Wired Connection 1 says Connecting, and will not connect

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, internet

I am having issues with my Ubuntu Machine that all of a sudden, it lost it's network connection. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS through VMWareWorkstation, but other machine on my VMNet Subnet are working without issues. (Same NAT settings, etc etc.)

The Icon for the Ethernet Adapter is just spinning and doesn't connect.

I've deleted the NIC, and added a new one to no avail. Both on Ubuntu and VMWare.

I've ran dhclient on the ENS intefaces, did an ifconfig up down and all doesn't seem to work.

```
ubuntu@Mothership:~$ ifconfig 
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    ether 02:42:47:09:46:32  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:0c:29:82:82:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2670  bytes 590881 (577.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 371  bytes 47280 (46.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 7068  bytes 479428 (468.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 7068  bytes 479428 (468.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In my /etc/network/interfaces I have the following:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Could it just be a bad cable? Or it sounds like a VM, and the host system has no problems

Answer (score 0):

We need to narrow down the problem, as currently there are too many culprits.

Firstly, bypass dhcp. On the interface you are supposed to get network, manually enter an IP address and the corresponding gateway in network manager. So, if you are supposed to get an IP in 192.168.2.0/24; then assign yourself the IP 192.168.2.202 (or something that you are sure won't collide with it) and also enter the gateway.

Get this info from another VM if need be.

Next, check the settings via:

```
ifconfig 
sudo mii-tool
```

At this point, it should work (if it is only a dhcp problem).

Next, check your routing table, does it have routes that don't make sense? Delete them.

Lastly check dmesg for issues is nothing gets caught.

Comment: What's a route that doesn't make sense, and how would one be deleted?

Comment: @Xen2050 issue command  sudo route -n  ; see the list of routes connecting you to the internet. Internet is destination 0.0.0.0 , mask 255.255.255.255. This destination will have a gateway and a phy associated with it (like ens0, eth0, etc.). If you have multiple such routes to internet, the one that routes you via a gateway that you know doesn't connect to internet - that's a bad route. Delete it using the route command (sudo route del .... )

Comment: This shows the following:

ubuntu@Mothership:~$ sudo route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.95.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 ens33
   169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
   172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
   192.168.95.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33

Comment: I assigned a static IP address to the subnet that it is supposed to be on. It now shows a 192.168.95.202 address with a subnet mask of /24 and gateway as .1.

There is still no internet. @DomoNCar

Comment: @WeAreOne Your network configuration is perfect. This means there is no issue on the client side of the things. Your issue isn't Linux related, it is on VMWare configuration side. What this means: Ubuntu is able to operate the network device, it is able to configure it, but the interface isn't receiving anything. As an aside, try this: sudo mii-tool